# Creating a Web Wrapper for COM and OCX

Tags: c#, asp.net

Today we have a windows application that, using an OCX, creates a web page (visible by a WebBrowser control in a small .NET WinForm application) and communicates through COM to the main application/client. (not relevant but this is Pascal)

I'm currently responsible to re create this application in a web environment so we can have the same functionality shared through Web as the user can see the same in a Web Browser.

The Windows application has almost 4 years on it and I need to re create everything from scratch, and all the bugs/features find in the future in the Windows Application I have to re create them again in the Web...

**Ohh well, you can see where this will end.**

I was thinking... is there any way I can create a Wrapper, even using 3rd party commercial objects, to:

- Communicate with the COM Object
- Can expose the content of the OCX

(this in my most confortable language, ASP.NET C#, but other are welcome)

> I was thinking out loud, can this be accomplish with a Java Applet? Silverlight 4?

Any ideas or any point to the right road will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to consider using [Silverlight 4](http://silverlight.net/getstarted/silverlight-4/). Although it's not fully baked (Microsoft announced it as Release Candidate status yesterday or today) it has COM support but will run in a web enabled way.

The fact that your previous application is Windows/OCX tells me that the chief weakness of this approach, which would be platform neutrality, is less of an issue.